# Having problem with web scraping with bs4 in python

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My program returns different numbers each time. If I run each page individually it gives out the right results. I wanted to get all the links which have 3 or more votes.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas
pg = 1
url ="https://stackoverflow.com/search?page="+str(pg)+"&tab=Relevance&q=scrappy%20python"
src = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(src,'html.parser')
pages = soup.findAll('a',{'class' : 's-pagination--item js-pagination-item'})
number_of_pages = len(pages)
print(number_of_pages)
qualified=[]


while pg<=number_of_pages:
    print("In Page :"+str(pg))
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=" + str(pg) + "&tab=Relevance&q=scrappy%20python"
    src = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs(src, 'html.parser')
    a_links = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'question-hyperlink'})
    span_links = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'vote-count-post'})
    hrefs = []
    for a_link in a_links:
        hrefs.append(a_link.get('href'))
    for link in range(len(span_links)):
        vote = span_links[link].strong.text
        n = int(vote)
        if n>2:
            the_link = 'https://stackoverflow.com' + hrefs[link]
            qualified.append(the_link)
            print(len(qualified))

    pg +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

`print(len(qualified))` will show the length of the full list that is your error. You can get how many links in each by adding `i = 0` after `while pg<=number_of_pages:` and `i += 1` after `if n>2:` then add `print(i)` before or after `pg +=1`.
Then code will be like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas
pg = 1
url ="https://stackoverflow.com/search?page="+str(pg)+"&tab=Relevance&q=scrappy%20python"
src = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs(src,'html.parser')
pages = soup.findAll('a',{'class' : 's-pagination--item js-pagination-item'})
number_of_pages = len(pages)
print(number_of_pages)
qualified=[]


while pg<=number_of_pages:
    i = 0
    print("In Page :"+str(pg))
    url = "https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=" + str(pg) + "&tab=Relevance&q=scrappy%20python"
    src = requests.get(url).text
    soup = bs(src, 'html.parser')
    a_links = soup.findAll('a',{'class':'question-hyperlink'})
    span_links = soup.findAll('span',{'class':'vote-count-post'})
    hrefs = []
    for a_link in a_links:
        hrefs.append(a_link.get('href'))
    for link in range(len(span_links)):
        vote = span_links[link].strong.text
        n = int(vote)
        if n>2:
            i += 1
            the_link = 'https://stackoverflow.com' + hrefs[link]
            qualified.append(the_link)
    print(i)

    pg +=1
#print(qualified)
```

Output:

```
6
In Page :1
1
In Page :2
4
In Page :3
2
In Page :4
3
In Page :5
2
In Page :6
2
```

Comment: It still gives me different outputs.                                                                                            
6 
In Page :1
0
In Page :2
0
In Page :3
0
In Page :4
0
In Page :5
0
In Page :6
0